# Group records by month and count them - Mongoose, nodeJs, mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to query in database (mongoose) and get back the number of sales made each month of the year for one particular product (within one year period).

I am new to node and mongoDb and I have come with a 'dummy' solution where I query in database and get back all the results for one product and than I use 3 loops to split the results in months but I think that it uses more resources than it should and it will use even more if it gets filled with more data, so I need help making a database query to solve that problem.

***Here is the part of my code that does that:***

> Assuming that the results are required from ***17-02-2020*** to ***17-02-2019***,
>   I know that if it is from ***January*** to ***December*** it will go into one loop for nothing
>   but I have another part of code which controls if it requires 1 year
>   result ex: ***01-01-2020*** to ***31-12-2020*** it will not execute the code
>   below, that code I am talking about has only one loop lol.

```
let startTime = performance.now();
Sales.find({productId:req.params.productId, "created_at": { "$gte": oneYearFromNow, "$lte": dateNow}}).then(result => {
        let newMonthsArray= new Array();
        let monthsArray = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October', 'November','December'];
        let months = {};
        for(let i=parseInt(req.params.startDate.substring(5,7))-1; i<12; i++){
            let year = parseInt(req.params.startDate.substring(0,4))-1;
            let month = parseInt(req.params.startDate.substring(5,7));
            newMonth = monthsArray[i] + '-' + year;
            newMonthsArray.push(newMonth);
            months[newMonth] = 0; 
        }

        for(let i=0; i<parseInt(req.params.startDate.substring(5,7)); i++){
            let year = parseInt(req.params.startDate.substring(0,4));
            let month = parseInt(req.params.startDate.substring(5,7));
            newMonth = monthsArray[i] + '-' + year;
            newMonthsArray.push(newMonth);
            months[newMonth] = 0; 
          }

        for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
            let getDate = result[i].created_at.toISOString();
            let year = getDate.substring(0,4);
            let month = parseInt(getDate.substring(5,7));
            let monthName = monthsArray[month-1];
            let date =  monthName + '-' + year;
            let count = Number(months[date]) + 1;
            months[date] = count;
        }

        let endTime = performance.now();
        res.status(200).send({Data: months, 'Execution time': endTime - startTime + ' mls'});
    });
```

> I hope everything is clear, I think I
>   need to use aggregation but I'm not sure how!

***Sample data:***

```
{
    {
        "created_at": "2020-04-04T17:02:07.832Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-04T17:02:07.832Z",
        "_id": "5e88bdcda3080736ac70f9c1",
        "price": 16800,
        "productId": "5e88bf90b9e5102ae46b154e",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-04-04T17:02:07.832Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-04T17:02:07.832Z",
        "_id": "5e88bdf9a3080736ac70f9c2",
        "price": 12800,
        "productId": "5e88bf90b9e5102ae46b154e",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

***Desired result:***

[image]

Comment: It would be better to understand if you post sample data + expected result, because it seems we can do this logic in the MongoDB side with aggregation

Comment: @Valijon sorry I forgot about that.. I just made those changes. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an aggregation query which returns the expected output. Some sample documents:

```
[
  { created_at: "2020-04-04T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 1 },
  { created_at: "2020-02-01T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 1 },
  { created_at: "2020-02-19T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 1 },
  { created_at: "2019-05-22T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 1 },
  { created_at: "2020-01-15T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 1 },
  { created_at: "2020-01-30T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 2 },  // not selected
  { created_at: "2019-03-15T17:02:07.832Z", productId: 1 }   // not selected
]
```

The input variables and the aggregation:

```
let TODAY = "2020-04-06T23:59:59"
let YEAR_BEFORE = "2019-04-07T00:00:00"
let req = { params: { productId: 1 } }
const monthsArray = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ]

db.sales.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          productId: req.params.productId, 
          created_at: { $gte: YEAR_BEFORE, $lte: TODAY }
      }
  },
  { 
      $group: {
          _id: { "year_month": { $substrCP: [ "$created_at", 0, 7 ] } }, 
          count: { $sum: 1 }
      } 
  },
  {
      $sort: { "_id.year_month": 1 }
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0, 
          count: 1, 
          month_year: { 
              $concat: [ 
                 { $arrayElemAt: [ monthsArray, { $subtract: [ { $toInt: { $substrCP: [ "$_id.year_month", 5, 2 ] } }, 1 ] } ] },
                 "-", 
                 { $substrCP: [ "$_id.year_month", 0, 4 ] }
              ] 
          }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          data: { $push: { k: "$month_year", v: "$count" } }
      } 
  },
  {
      $project: { 
          data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" }, 
          _id: 0 
      } 
  }
] )
```

The output:

```
{
        "data" : {
                "May-2019" : 1,
                "January-2020" : 1,
                "February-2020" : 2,
                "April-2020" : 1
        }
}
```

---

Here is the **updated aggregation**.

Note the following changes: (1) new constants FIRST_MONTH and LAST_MONTH, (2) changed the `monthsArray` variable name to MONTHS_ARRAY, (3) added 3 new pipeline stages.

The first two pipeline stages (new) build a template with all the months (covering the from and to input date range). The third new stage merges the template with the output data derived from the previous aggregation.

```
const FIRST_MONTH = 1
const LAST_MONTH = 12
const MONTHS_ARRAY = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ]

let TODAY = "2020-04-06T23:59:59"
let YEAR_BEFORE = "2019-04-07T00:00:00"

db.sales.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          productId: req.params.productId, 
          created_at: { $gte: YEAR_BEFORE, $lte: TODAY }
      }
  },
  { 
      $group: {
          _id: { "year_month": { $substrCP: [ "$created_at", 0, 7 ] } }, 
          count: { $sum: 1 }
      } 
  },
  {
      $sort: { "_id.year_month": 1 }
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          _id: 0, 
          count: 1, 
          month_year: { 
              $concat: [ 
                 { $arrayElemAt: [ monthsArray, { $subtract: [ { $toInt: { $substrCP: [ "$_id.year_month", 5, 2 ] } }, 1 ] } ] },
                 "-", 
                 { $substrCP: [ "$_id.year_month", 0, 4 ] }
              ] 
          }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          data: { $push: { k: "$month_year", v: "$count" } }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          start_year: { $substrCP: [ YEAR_BEFORE, 0, 4 ] }, 
          end_year: { $substrCP: [ TODAY, 0, 4 ] },
          months1: { $range: [ { $toInt: { $substrCP: [ YEAR_BEFORE, 5, 2 ] } }, { $add: [ LAST_MONTH, 1 ] } ] },
          months2: { $range: [ FIRST_MONTH, { $add: [ { $toInt: { $substrCP: [ TODAY, 5, 2 ] } }, 1 ] } ] }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          template_data: { 
              $concatArrays: [ 
                  { $map: { 
                       input: "$months1", as: "m1",
                       in: {
                           count: 0,
                           month_year: { 
                               $concat: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ MONTHS_ARRAY, { $subtract: [ "$$m1", 1 ] } ] }, "-",  "$start_year" ] 
                           }                                            
                       }
                  } }, 
                  { $map: { 
                       input: "$months2", as: "m2",
                       in: {
                           count: 0,
                           month_year: { 
                               $concat: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ MONTHS_ARRAY, { $subtract: [ "$$m2", 1 ] } ] }, "-",  "$end_year" ] 
                           }                                            
                       }
                  } }
              ] 
         }
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          data: { 
             $map: { 
                 input: "$template_data", as: "t",
                 in: {   
                     k: "$$t.month_year",
                     v: { 
                         $reduce: { 
                             input: "$data", initialValue: 0, 
                             in: {
                                 $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$t.month_year", "$$this.k"] },
                                              { $add: [ "$$this.v", "$$value" ] },
                                              { $add: [ 0, "$$value" ] }
                                 ]
                             }
                         } 
                     }
                 }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  {
      $project: { 
          data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" }, 
          _id: 0 
      } 
  }
] )
```

***The output:***

```
{
        "data" : {
                "April-2019" : 0,
                "May-2019" : 1,
                "June-2019" : 0,
                "July-2019" : 0,
                "August-2019" : 0,
                "September-2019" : 0,
                "October-2019" : 0,
                "November-2019" : 0,
                "December-2019" : 0,
                "January-2020" : 1,
                "February-2020" : 2,
                "March-2020" : 0,
                "April-2020" : 1
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, how would I add also the months that don't have any sales, because I plan to show them in a graph.. I also had to make this changes at `$match` in order for that code to work for me: `$expr: {
                    $and: [
                        {created_at: ['$lte', todayDate]},
                        {created_at: ['$gte', oneYearBefore]}
                    ]
                }`

Comment: **(1)** The syntax `created_at: { $gte: YEAR_BEFORE, $lte: TODAY }` _and_ `$expr: { $and: [ {created_at: ['$lte', todayDate]}, {created_at: ['$gte', oneYearBefore]} ] }` has the _same functionality_. The variable names - you can use as per your convenience. **(2)** _"how would I add also the months that don't have any sales..."_: I will try to find what is possible.

Comment: Yes I know that it has the same funcionality but when I used the format you wrote for some reason it always returned empty array (without any data). As far as months without any sales I think the best approach would be to use those 2 loops (those loops can be seen in my question) to create an object cointaining all of the months and then after the db query is done, I can loop throgh the object I created with loops and when the keys match I simply attach the value that represents that month (which are returned from db). Please let me know what you think for that approach.

Comment: I noted your comments. I will get back sometime tomorrow with something to work with.

Comment: I have updated the answer to get the output with all the months.

Comment: Thank you it gives the desired result now :)

Comment: @prasad_ Could you please help to modify the query to not show the months that are greater than TODAY date? By the way wonderful answer. It helped me a lot

Comment: @AugustinJose You can do a filter on the array data from the stage before the last `$project` stage.

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you for the quick response. I am not that good at Mongo queries. Do you mind elaborating this with a detailed answer?

Comment: @prasad_ I have `"createdAt": "2021-09-16T05:57:56.858Z",` type of date this date format using  **timestamps**  in mongoose So I want to get selected month record using this timestamp and one thing I have pass the month from Postman or frontend ,I have also tried lot of solutions and lot of searches but I cant found perfect solution for that . can you help me out in my problem Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right that you need to use aggregation. This should work:

```
// NOTE: It is important that the the month strings start from the second element in this array  
// becuase the $month operator returns month values as numbers from 1 to 12.
const monthStrings = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
Sales.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // Match only salses with a specific productId
      productId: req.params.productId,
      // Match only salses that fufils the date constraint below
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $gt: ["$created_at", oneYearFromNow] },
          { $lt: ["$created_at", dateNow] }
        ],
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
       // Group by both month and year of the sale
      _id: {
        month: { $month: "$created_at" },
        year: { $year: "$created_at" },
      },
      // Count the no of sales
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  // Adding a project here to just to format the group date better
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              monthStrings,
              "$_id.month"
            ]
          },
          "-",
          "$_id.year"
        ]
      },
      count: 1,
    }
  }
])
```

You can test the aggregation pipeline in this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HqYFiiKoljK).

The output would be an array of objects like this:

```
{ "_id": *,  "count": * }
```

Where the value of _id is a string in the format `<month>-<year>`(e.g `April-2019`) representing the month and year of sale. The count value is the number of sales that happened that month/year.

I used a combination of $match, $group and $project stages in the aggregation pipeline, you can find more details on how the stages work [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) respectively.

Comment: Thank you, yes your solution works fine but I had to make some changes on the _**$expr/$and** field_ because the format you wrote always return an **empty array** I don't know why, but it would be nice if I can get an explanation on that. _**Changes made:**_ Instead of `{ $gt: ["created_at", date]}` I wrote `{created_at: ['$gt', date]}` the same applies for _**$lt field**_

Comment: Also when I put dates for ex: _from:_ **06.04.2019** _to:_ **06.04.2020** results for _April_ of **2019** and **2020** are summed together. ex: `April 2019 has 20 sales and April 2020 has 10 sales` _**in the end I get back**_ `_id: 4 and count: 30` meaning  `20 + 10 = 30` Is it possible to split those records like so: `April 2019: 20` `April 2020: 10`

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you had to change the way the date filters was written to get it to work, the syntax I posted worked fine in the playground, I would try to dig deeper on that. As for the second comment, we would need to group by both year and month, I would update the answer for this.

Comment: Hello, yes that reply that I marked as an answer does that, but even there I had to make those changes that I made in your reply in order to get it work, I don't know why but it would be nice to get an explanation for that. Thank you