# How to return count for each month in the selected timeframe

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want my mongo query to return the count for each MONTH. The below query returns the count for each company id for the date entered.

E.g the return result would be each month showing the companyID and the count for the month.

Just to confirm the query works fine, I am just after the monthly return.

```
var from = new Date("2020-02-20T01:54:00")
var to = new Date("2020-03-25T01:54:00")
// uncomment if you wish `to` date to by NOW
// var to = ISODate()
var minimumRecordsNumber = 3;
var unixFrom = from.getTime() / 1000;
var unixTo = to.getTime() / 1000;
var heading = 'Timeframe\nfrom: ' + from + '\nto: ' + to + '\n\n'
var cursor = db.getCollection('registrations').aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        'created': {'$gte': unixFrom , '$lte': unixTo},
    }
},{
    '$group': {
        '_id': {'companyID': '$companyID', 'eventID': '$eventID'}, 
        'count': {'$sum': NumberInt(1)}}
},{
    '$match': {
        'count': {'$gte': minimumRecordsNumber},
    }
}])
var companies = {};
var events = [];
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    var data = cursor.next()
    var companyID = data._id.companyID
    var eventID = data._id.eventID
    if (events.indexOf(eventID) === -1) {
        events.push(eventID)
        if (! companies[companyID]) {
            companies[companyID] = 1
        } else {
            companies[companyID]++
        }
    }
}
print(heading + tojson(companies))
```

Comment: See this similar post with an answer: [Group records by month and count them - Mongoose, nodeJs, mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051225/group-records-by-month-and-count-them-mongoose-nodejs-mongodb/61062406#61062406)

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are stored in MongoDB as a date type, not string, you could use the [$year](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/index.html#year-aggregation) and [$month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/index.html#month-aggregation) aggregation operators in the group _id.

```
db.getCollection('registrations').aggregate([
    {'$match': {'created': {'$gte': unixFrom , '$lte': unixTo}}},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': {
                'companyID': '$companyID', 
                'eventID': '$eventID', 
                'year': {$year: "$created"},
                'month': {$month: "$created"}
               } 
        'count': {'$sum': NumberInt(1)}
    }},
    {'$match': {
        'count': {'$gte': minimumRecordsNumber},
    }}
])
```