# MongoDB Aggregate by date on many fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have the following schema (abbreviated!)

```
{
    date: {
        _id: false,
        day: { type: Number },
        month: { type: Number },
        year: { type: Number },
    },
    flightTimes: {
        _id: false,
        totalTime: Number,
        ...
    },
    loggedTimes: {
        _id: false,
        P1: {
            type: Number,
        },
        P2: {
            type: Number,
        },
        ...
    },
    customFields: [
        {
            _id: false,
            value: String,
            type: {
                type: String,
                enum: ["text", "number", "time", "yesno", "paragraph"],
                required: true,
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

I am trying to produce the following output using aggregation, but struggling.

```
{
    total: [10,20,30],
    P1: [45, 55, 12],
    P2: [0, 12, 15],
}
```

Where the 1st item in the total array is the sum of any documents where Month = 1 (January), the second is the sum for February etc.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?  For bonus points: the array should have a 0 if no documents match the current month.  For more bonus points: how could I create an additional array for the sum of values in each custom field where type = time.

Ultimately looking to produce a graph with Charts.JS which shows the sum per month for each category of time.

Comment: Can you show some data and expected result for that data set?

Comment: Here is a similar post which produces output like `total`: [Group records by month and count them - Mongoose, nodeJs, mongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051225/group-records-by-month-and-count-them-mongoose-nodejs-mongodb/61062406#61062406).