# MongoDB create empty results object

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this inside my database Mongo:

```
/*Order:*/

{
date_order: ISODate("2020-08-02T22:00:00.000Z"),
item: 'banana'
price: '2$'
}
```

Here is my code Mongo to get each day's total orders for a week from 27/07 (Monday) to 02/08 (Sunday):

```
db.getCollection('order').aggregate([
    {$match: { date_order: {$gte: new Date('2020-07-27T22:00:00Z') , $lt: ISODate("2020-08-02T23:59:59Z")}}},
    {$group: {
        _id: {$dayOfWeek: '$date_order'},
        nbOfOrders: {$sum: 1}
    }},
    { $project: {
        '_id': 0,
        'dayOfWeek': { $subtract: ['$_id', 1] },
        'nbOfOrders': '$nbOfOrders'
        }
    }
])
```

It gives me the results:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 0.0, // 0 for MONDAY
    "nbOfOrders" : 4.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 4.0, // 4 for FRIDAY
    "nbOfOrders" : 4.0
}
```

All the other days except for on Monday and Friday, nobody orders anything. How should I do to record those days with no orders? I want to have a result like this:

```
/* MONDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 0.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 4.0
}

/* TUESDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 1.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 0.0
}

/* WEDNESDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 2.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 0.0
}

/* THURSDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 3.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 0.0
}

/* FRIDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 4.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 4.0
}

/* SATURDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 5.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 0.0
}

/* SUNDAY */
{
    "dayOfWeek" : 6.0,
    "nbOfOrders" : 0.0
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar post with an answer: [Group records by month and count them - Mongoose, nodeJs, mongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051225/group-records-by-month-and-count-them-mongoose-nodejs-mongodb/61062406#61062406). Note the output in that post is grouping by month (not week). I think you can apply similar logic to your aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store predefined empty values array in a variable,

```
let dayOfWeek = [ 
    {"dayOfWeek": 0, "nbOfOrders": 0},
    {"dayOfWeek": 1, "nbOfOrders": 0},
    {"dayOfWeek": 2, "nbOfOrders": 0},
    {"dayOfWeek": 3, "nbOfOrders": 0},
    {"dayOfWeek": 4, "nbOfOrders": 0},
    {"dayOfWeek": 5, "nbOfOrders": 0},
    {"dayOfWeek": 6, "nbOfOrders": 0} ]
```

Aggregation query: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BtgaXVY7TQb),

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date_order: {
        $gte: ISODate("2020-07-27T22:00:00Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2020-08-10T23:59:59Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $dayOfWeek: "$date_order" },
      nbOfOrders: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      dayOfWeek: {
        $subtract: ["$_id", 1]
      },
      nbOfOrders: "$nbOfOrders"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      items: {
        "$concatArrays": ["$items", dayOfWeek]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$items.dayOfWeek",
      nbOfOrders: { $sum: "$items.nbOfOrders" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      dayOfWeek: "$_id",
      nbOfOrders: "$nbOfOrders"
    }
  }
])
```

> **Note:** When you do with aggregation query it is totally lengthy process, and decrease the performance of your query, i am talking about particular this required result,
>
> my suggestion is to do it out of query using loop, because there is only countable 7 days of week and loop is faster than this query,
>
> I am not adding loop examples here because, I am not sure about which language you are using.

Comment: Hi @turivishal can you tell me why query is a slower option?

Comment: @Ibrahim Look at the pipelines step by step, last 5 pipelines just for creating this output, and we know only exact 7 records will be final documents, so loop is faster than these 5 pipelines.

Comment: @HảiTrungPhạm have you resolved your problem with this answer? is there anything problem then let me know will try to solve.