# Api to list ordered product count based on date using node js and mongoDB express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Node.js:**
how to create api for list ordered product count based on date .this order model and how to i create the controller for that...

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const schema = mongoose.Schema
    const orderSchema = new schema({
      orderID:{type:String,required:true},
      customer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'userdatas',
      },
      orderItems:
      {
        // productName: { type: String, required: true },
        // qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        // amount: { type: String, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'productsdatas',
        },
      },

      shippingAddress : {
        address: { type: String, required: true },
        city: { type: String, required: true },
        postalCode : { type: String, required: true },
        country: { type: String, required: true },
      },

      orderDate:{type: String,
        required: true},
      totalAmount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0,
      },
    },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    )
    const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
    
    module.exports = Order
```

**mongoDB:**
this is mongoDB data for  order i should already created and customer and product details i populateded  to show the output that time..

```
        {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f47d44a772822d2370794"
  },
  "orderID": "1",
  "customerName": "vikiram",
  "customer": {
    "$oid": "630ccd62121a7425d6918e95"
  },
  "orderItems": {
    "product": {
      "$oid": "630d95d659998496b12f4f36"
    }
  },
  "shippingAddress": {
    "address": "123 IT street",
    "city": "chennai",
    "postalCode": "6000100",
    "country": "india"
  },
  "orderDate": "25/04/2022",
  "totalAmount": 11700000,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1650886612732"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1661945812732"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

**json:**
i want json  output in postman like this..

```
{
        "data" : {
                "May-2019" : 1,
                "January-2020" : 1,
                "February-2020" : 2,
                "April-2020" : 1
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group records by month and count them - Mongoose, nodeJs, mongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051225/group-records-by-month-and-count-them-mongoose-nodejs-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using aggregation. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Check `$count`, `$sort` and `$project` operators in aggregation.

Comment: bro i got the api code from  stack overflow but i dont know actually how to use my task ...

Comment: What do you mean by API Code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051225/group-records-by-month-and-count-them-mongoose-nodejs-mongodb